# Exercise (Big-Oh): How do find intersection of two functions where n = 100 for example

Tags: algorithm, big-o, rate

I am trying to understand how n^2 is faster than nlogn for n < 100 and opposite when n >= 100. In general this is not the case but this is an exercise that I do not want an answer for but to lead me to the right direction. I can picture two function in a graph that intersection at n = 100 as n < 100 O(n^2) is faster and as n > 100 O(nlogn) is faster.

I came up with an^2+b and c*nlog(n)+d

The key to my understanding here is constant that makes the differences. But what is hard is that I need to come up with constants that will satisfy the above scenario. Is there a way or technique that is done or am I going correctly on the wrong direction?

Original question: James and Brad are arguing about the performance of their sorting algorithms. James claims that hisO(N logN)-time algorithm is always faster than Brad's O(N2)-time algorithm. To settle the issue, they implement and run the two algorithms on many randomly generated data sets. To James' dismay, they find that if N < 100 the O(N2)-time algorithm actually runs faster, and only when N >= 100 the O(N logN)-time one is better. Explain why the above scenario is possible. You may give numerical examples.

Comment: what they are asking you is to solve `a 100^2 = c 100 log(100)`

Answer (score 1):

Take the formulas you already have, an^2+b and c*nlog(n)+d

Replace n with 100, and set them equal. That will show you the relationships between a, b, c, and d. Select a set of values that conform to that constraint.

Comment: wouldn't I need another arbitrary value that sets it equal to each function, for example: an^2+b=z and c*nlog(n)+d=z and then solving it?

Comment: I would skip the step of setting them both equal to z, and just set them equal to each other. The first step in solving the system with z would be to get rid of it anyway.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on it more? I'm drawing in a blank. a*10000+b=c*100*log(100)+d .. log(100) doesn't look pretty if there is a base other than 10 (which in this case is 2). How do I go about finding a? a= c*100*log(100)+d-b/10000 ?

Comment: log_2(x) == log_10(x)/log_10(2).

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking about what each variable in each equation means. I would go ahead and ignore certain variables (set them to 0 or 1 as necessary) and focus on what deciding variables left mean. What do each A, B, C, and D mean and what are each of these variables bounds? For instance, negative runtime is not a thing so no variable can be negative. Sounds obvious, but the question was direction, not substance. For added benefit, try making A = C = 1 and manipulate B and D.

Comment: That does make sense, if I was to do A = C = 1 to manipulate B and D, I would have to give D = 0 if I was to find B or give B = 0 if I was to find D, correct?

Comment: That's it. If you add numbers to illustrate that's fine, but showing that Brad's program runs slower because it has some sort of initial value to be faster - like many programs :)

Comment: You said no variable can be negative but yet when I try to manipulate for the constant b and d by giving one or the other 0, I came up with b = -9336 and d = +9336. Here is my work: if a=c=1 and d=0 to determine b.. (1)(100)^2+b=(1)(100)(6.64)+(0) => (1)(10000)+b=(664)+(0) => 10000+b=664+0 => b=664-10000 => b=-9,336. I did the same thing for d when a=c=1 and b = 0 but I get +9,336 for that. Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't say the constants couldn't be negative. I said that runtime could not be negative. You can solve the equation with negative runtimes along the curve, but those values would be out of bounds with reality